# Scope variable in AngularJS returning undefined

Tags: undefined, angularjs-scope

I am working on a little app and I have a service that goes and gets some data and returns it as JSON. I am able to display that data in my HTML just fine. But if I try define a new $scope variable from part of the data that came back the newly defined variable is undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a bit of my code:

```
kanban.controller('WorkRequestController', function ($scope, $routeParams, workRequestService, workTypeService){

$scope.init = function(){
    $scope.workRequest = workRequestService.getWorkRequest($routeParams.cardId);
    $scope.workTypes = workTypeService.getAllWorkTypes();

    $scope.id = $scope.workRequest.id;
};

$scope.submit = function(){;
    console.log($scope.id);
};
```

});